# Highlight cell row conditional formatting excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, conditional-formatting

| CheckCell | firstValue | second Value | ThirdValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 50 | 0 | 51 | 0 |
| 51 | 33 | 45 | 66 |
| 3 | 1 | 4 | 8 |

i've put the formula in conditonal formatting and mark each cell

SOLUTION TRIED

```
=OR ($b1>$a1 , $c1>$a1, $d1>$a1)
```

it should apply formula to all rows, values in cell b,c,d, for the second row should be compared with 51 not 50.
Thanks. any help will be appreciated and only those cells should be highlighted,

[image]

second attempt try( with a new formula)
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use the rule:

```
=B2>$A2
```

and apply it to the cells B2:D4.

[image]

Comment: hi, this didn't work, did you miss the "$" with b2 but even with that it didn't work , how does it compare row two with 51 and 8 with 3 .
can you replcae last row with 100 78 101 200 and see

Comment: Yup, you applied to A2:D4, not B2:D4.

Comment: Also your formula doesn't match this answer. Please *carefully* implement the answer, noting there's only a `$` before A2.

Comment: It will certainly work, some of the numbers are left aligned, may be they are reading as text instead of numbers. And A2 will be absolute relative reference . Note to @user12063090